# Word web add in using dialog box

Tags: dialog, word-web-addins

I know that the dynamic ribbon buttons or menus does not supported on Web Add in projects yet,and wonder if any improvements has been made about this . In fact, my main problem is : I'm trying to run my web Add in on a Dialog Box, not in the task pane but when I try to get custom properties of an Office Word document, I am able to do this from task pane but can't do the same on Dialog Box. When I try the code below I get a RichApi.Error:AccessDenied. I've checked the domains but could not find any problem. Any suggestions?`

```
    async function readCustomDocumentProperties5() {
            await Word.run(async (context) => {
                let properties = context.document.properties.customProperties;
                properties.load("key,type,value");


                await context.sync();

                for (var i = 0; i < properties.items.length; i++)
                    console.log(
                        "Property Name:" +
                        properties.items[i].key +
                        "; Type=" +
                        properties.items[i].type +
                        "; Property Value=" +
                        properties.items[i].value
                    );
          
            });
        }
```

The error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) RichApi.Error: AccessDenied
at new n (word-win32-16.01.js:26)
at n.i.processRequestExecutorResponseMessage (word-win32-16.01.js:26)
at word-win32-16.01.js:26
at async Dialog.html?_host_Info=Word$Win32$16.01$tr-TR$telemetry$isDialog$$0:47
at async readCustomDocumentProperties5 (Dialog.html?_host_Info=Word$Win32$16.01$tr-TR$telemetry$isDialog$$0:42)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Important: You don't have access to office context in the iframe or new window as dialog. But there is a work-around here.

You are opening the Dialog from the ribbon using an `execute function` type. Right?

The solution is to do the modifications in the functions file where you opened the dialog. With help of `Office.context.ui.messageParent(your object as json or whatever you need to pass)`. So on the button clicks you message the functions file and you have access to the office application context there.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for your answer!. You've cleared my mind.

Comment: @TunaAlpan Great to hear that